# Error: Cannot create a MobileFirst project within another project

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I am trying to create a project with mfp create (version 7.1) and i get the following error:

Error: Could not create MobileFirst Project.
Error: Cannot create a MobileFirst project within another project.

I have an older version of Worklight on the same machine. Anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

That is not what the error is saying.

Lets take the following scenario:

1. cd Desktop
2. mfp create myproject
3. cd myproject
4. mfp create myproject 2

You cannot create a project within a project.
That is what the error is saying. It's not related to any older installation.

If this is not your scenario. What is your scenario?

Comment: As you have suggested, i have tried to eliminate the potential of being under another project by going directly to the user folder and try to create the project.  I just installed mfp tool this morning and try to create a project by mfp create project_name. I am not sure if there are any other dependency.  I checked the node libraries inside the mobilefirst installation directory and i see reference to cordova cli. If you know any dependency of the cli tool, let me know.

Comment: When i run the command, i have the following error:  `Error: Could not create MobileFirst Project.
Error: Cannot create a MobileFirst project within another project.`

Comment: Provide a fuller image and do not hide the path obviously(!). Create a dummy app.

Answer (score 0):

I have downgraded my node from 0.12 to 0.10.38 and this solved the problem. Not sure if this is the exact solution, but it fixed my problem. I have removed all the node_packages when i un-install node. Used brew to install 0.10.38.